# Angular 4 convert from UTC to specific timezone

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 application I have to convert a date like: `2018-01-16T11:29:48.151Z` in a locale date using a specific timezone.

I need a conversion from UTC to italy date/hour.

But if I use an instruction like this:

```
const newDate = new Date(res).toLocaleString('it-IT', {timeZone: 'Europe/Rome'})
```

I have a not valid string to be converted in a date for example: `16/1/2018, 12:30:29` because the final result needs to be a valid date/string

Is it possible to do this without any third part component.

Comment: I would suggest you to use moment.js library for any date manipulations as I found it more reliable. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I want to avoid it, I search an angular/typescript solution

Comment: there is nothing special with angular (or Typescript) regarding dates. It's Javascript dates that are used. Moment.js is a very nice addition, that integrates well (and easily) to any angular application, enabling you to use a more reliable and stable framework than the native Javascript handling. You can use moment.js in the code for the below `pipe` angular solution, for example.

Answer (score 1):

[**moment-timezone**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone)

**Install**

```
npm i moment-timezone
```

**Import**

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone'
```

**Use**

```
let june = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
console.log(june.tz('America/Los_Angeles')  // 5am PDT
console.log(june.tz('America/New_York'))    // 8am EDT
console.log(june.tz('Asia/Tokyo'))          // 9pm JST
console.log(june.tz('Australia/Sydney'))    // 10pm EST

let dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");
console.log(dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles'))  // 4am PST
console.log(dec.tz('America/New_York'))     // 7am EST
console.log(dec.tz('Asia/Tokyo'))           // 9pm JST
console.log(dec.tz('Australia/Sydney'))     // 11pm EST
```

**That much simple. Isn't it???**

Answer (score 0):

If you want a valid date string and if you upgrade to angular 5, you can use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) which has the `timeZone` parameter:

`date_expression | date[:format[:timezone[:locale]]]`

The parameter is new to Angular 5.

A few examples from [the page](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
<!--output 'Lundi 15 Juin 2015 à 09:03:01 GMT+01:00'-->
<p>The full date/time in french is: {{today | date:'full':'':'fr'}}</p>

<!--output '2015-06-15 05:03 PM GMT+9'-->
<p>The custom date is {{today | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}}</p>

<!--output '2015-06-15 09:03 AM GMT+9'-->
<p>The custom date with fixed timezone is {{fixedTimezone | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900'}}</p>
```

If you want to convert the date itself to stay as the date object, I'm not sure this helps. Date is in fact in all time zones at once and it only matters how you display it to the user.